# Crystal Reports API - chart: "for all records" or "for each record"?

Tags: api, crystal-reports

Is there any way to determine whether a chart in Crystal Reports 2008 (using either the RAS SDK or the older RDC API) is set to display values "for each record" or "for all records"?

I can get access to a `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ChartObject` but can't find any API there to access which type of chart it is - "for each" or "for all".

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any type of suitable enum searching the .NET libraries with reflector. I think it would be somewhere in the ChartDefinition object...maybe it is implied by the datafields collection...

good luck